How to connect, using terraform, the Azure Analysis Services Server (AASS) with an Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Factory (ADF)
Im planning to connect, using terraform, the azure analysis services server with an Azure SQL Database and Azure Data factory.
So far, the docs were not that useful, and I was wondering if you can gimme some example terraform code on how to achieve this or if you can provide some tutorial.
I d like to see how I can set up the network connection in a secure way between all these.
resource "azurerm_analysis_services_server" "server" {
  name                    = "analysisservicesserver"
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                     = "S0"
  admin_users             = ["myuser@domain.tld"]
  enable_power_bi_service = true

  ipv4_firewall_rule {
    name        = "myRule1"
    range_start = "210.117.252.0"
    range_end   = "210.117.252.255"
  }

  tags = {
    abc = 123
  }
}

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/analysis_services_server
Besides ipv4_firewall_rule  I dont see that many options on configuring the connectivity (private endpoint my be a requirement but its not clear yet)

I ll check it out. Thanks!


How to connect the Azure Analysis Services Server (AASS) with an Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Factory (ADF) using terraform.

As per MSDoc & github it seems Azure Analysis Services currently does not support private endpoints and there are few other approaches to consider one among them is Virtual Network Service Endpoints or Virtual Network rules.
Terraform configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vksb-rg"
  location = "East US2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "vksb-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.Storage"]
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "vksbsqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "example" {
  name                = "vksbdb"
  server_id           = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  collation           = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type        = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb         = 10  
  sku_name            = "S0"
  zone_redundant      = false
  read_scale          = false  
}

resource "azurerm_analysis_services_server" "example" {
  name                    = "vksbanalysisservicesserver"
  location                = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                     = "S0"
  admin_users             = ["v-bolliv@microsoft.com"]
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "vksbdf"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowSQL"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "1433"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowAnalysisServices"
    priority                   = 1002
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "80"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}


Deployment:



refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-database-paas-overview?view=azuresql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-vnet-gateway

Much appreciated!! Tbh I was looking for something similar to this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_managed_private_endpoint. Or something managed identities related. If that s an option ofc.
